# Pack/Unpack a buffer

Tags: c

I'm working a simple packet serialization program and I'm having a really hard time just creating the header for my packets. I'm creating a buffer and then trying to load the first two items into the buffer. I run memcopy but nothing actually ends up in the buffer and then when I try to unpack it I get a segmentation fault. Reading examples online I THINK I'm doing it right. Any help would be appreciated.

When print out the values of the uints there is data in each one.

```
void createHeader(int messageLength, char* message) {
  uint16_t version = 457;
  uint16_t htonsVersion = htons(version);
  uint16_t length = messageLength;
  uint16_t htonsLength = htons(length);
  char buffer[142];
  printf("%" PRIu16 "\n", version);
  printf("%" PRIu16 "\n", htonsVersion);
  printf("%" PRIu16 "\n",htonsLength);
  printf("%" PRIu16 "\n",length);
  memcpy(buffer+0, &htonsVersion, sizeof htonsVersion);
  memcpy(buffer+2, &htonsLength, sizeof htonsLength);
  printf("%s \n", "UNPACK");
  uint16_t* testPacketVersion;
  memcpy(testPacketVersion, buffer+0, sizeof buffer+0);
  uint16_t* testPacketMessage;
  //Segmentation fault happens here
  memcpy(testPacketMessage, buffer+2, sizeof buffer+2);
  char* returnMessage;

}
```

Comment: I'm not really looking for anyone to debug it. As my code shows above I've tried printing the values before they go into the buffer and the values are what is to be expected. I then copy the values into the buffer and try to pull them back off and get segmentation faults. I'm obviously making a mistake but I'm just not sure what mistake I'm making.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
uint16_t* testPacketVersion;
memcpy(testPacketVersion, buffer+0, sizeof buffer+0);
```

is very wrong. The pointer `testPacketVersion` is not initialized, so you're copying data to a random location in memory. Undefined behavior.

You shouldn't even have a pointer, since you want to create an actual `uint16_t`, it should just be:

```
uint16_t testPacketVersion;
memcpy(&testPacketVersion, buffer+0, sizeof testPacketVersion);
```

I also corrected the `sizeof` usage, since that was all wrong. You want to copy as many characters as required for the `uint16_t`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much for the help. That resolved that issue!